# Completely separate a git subdir to another repo

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I want to separate a subdir of git repo to an independent repo.

I found on another question here in SO a short guide to filter everything but the relevant folder (with `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter dir1 -- --all`), now I have a new git repo but with all the branches from the original - how can I get rid of all of the branches that haven't changed my subdir?

I thought doing it somehow with `rev-list`, `ls-tree` and then filter the branches contains the commits that touched my subdir.

I also don't know if my solution is practically good or it might have problems, theoretically it sounds fine to me.

Any ideas or maybe there's another/easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is probably to fetch or push just the filtered branches, e.g.

```
git init ../split
git push ../split newbranch
```